# "ftplib.error_perm: 550 Operation not permitted" when trying to download the second file from the same directory using FTP_TLS

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftp, ftps

**Got this error while running my script:** `ftplib.error_perm: 550 Operation not permitted`

ftpdownloader.py :

```
import ftplib
import threading
import logging
import os


class Client:
    def __init__(self, host, port, username, passwd):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.username = username
        self.passwd = passwd
        self.ftp = None
        self.set_ftp()
        self.login_to_ftp()

    def set_ftp(self):
        self.ftp = ftplib.FTP_TLS(self.host)
        self.ftp.set_debuglevel(True)
        self.ftp.set_pasv(True)

    def login_to_ftp(self):
        self.ftp.login(self.username, self.passwd)
        self.ftp.prot_p()

    def download_file(self, filename, local_filename=None):
        logging.info('Will download this file : "%s"', filename)
        if local_filename is None:
            local_filename = filename
        self.ftp.voidcmd('TYPE I')
        sock = self.ftp.transfercmd('RETR ' + filename)

        def background():
            with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
                while True:
                    block = sock.recv(1024 * 1024)
                    if not block:
                        break
                    f.write(block)
                logging.debug('will close sock ...')
                sock.close()

        t = threading.Thread(target=background)
        t.start()
        while t.is_alive():
            t.join(20)
            self.ftp.voidcmd('NOOP')
        # self.ftp.close()
        logging.info("File downloaded with success : %s", local_filename)

    def get_directories_list(self, directory_path):
        logging.debug('Getting directories of directory : %s', directory_path)
        directories_list = []
        for elem in self.ftp.mlsd(directory_path):
            if elem[1]['type'] == 'dir':
                directories_list += [elem[0]]
        return directories_list

    def get_files_list(self, directory_path):
        logging.debug('Getting files of directory : %s', directory_path)
        files_list = []
        for elem in self.ftp.mlsd(directory_path):
            if elem[1]['type'] == 'file':
                files_list += [elem[0]]
        return files_list

    def get_all_files_of_directory(self, ftp_directory_root, ftp_directory_path, output_directory_path):
        current_position = ftp_directory_root + ftp_directory_path
        current_output_directory = output_directory_path + ftp_directory_path
        # self.set_ftp()
        # self.login_to_ftp()
        files_list = self.get_files_list(current_position)
        directories_list = self.get_directories_list(current_position)

        os.makedirs(current_output_directory, exist_ok=True)

        for file in files_list:
            self.download_file(current_position + '/' + file, current_output_directory + '/' + file)
            # self.set_ftp()
            # self.login_to_ftp()

        for directory in directories_list:
            if ftp_directory_path == '/':
                ftp_directory_path = ''
            self.get_all_files_of_directory(ftp_directory_root, ftp_directory_path + '/' + directory,
                                            output_directory_path)
```

**Test script :**

test.py :

```
from ftpdownloader import Client

ftp_host_name = 'ftp-hostname'
ftp_port = 21
ftp_username = 'username'
ftp_password = '*******'

client = Client(ftp_host_name, ftp_port, ftp_username, ftp_password)
client.get_all_files_of_directory('/directory1', '/', 'downloads/test')
```

**FTP content :**

```
 - directory1:
   - directory11:
     - file111.xml
     - file112.zip
   - directory12:
     - file121.xml
     - file122.zip
```

When I run my test.py script (with commented lines on ftpdownloader.py), the script :

- Got the list of directories and files
- Download the first founded file (file111.xml)
- ***ERROR*** when trying to download the second file (file112.zip)-> `ftplib.error_perm: 550 Operation not permitted`

**FTP_TLS debug logs :**

```
*cmd* 'TYPE A'
*resp* '200 Type set to A'
*cmd* 'PASV'
*resp* '227 Entering Passive Mode (81,252,220,78,234,106).'
*cmd* 'MLSD /directory1'
*resp* '150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for MLSD'
*resp* '226 Transfer complete'
*cmd* 'TYPE A'
*resp* '200 Type set to A'
*cmd* 'PASV'
*resp* '227 Entering Passive Mode (81,252,220,78,234,187).'
*cmd* 'MLSD /directory1'
*resp* '150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for MLSD'
*resp* '226 Transfer complete'
*cmd* 'TYPE A'
*resp* '200 Type set to A'
*cmd* 'PASV'
*resp* '227 Entering Passive Mode (81,252,220,78,234,99).'
*cmd* 'MLSD /directory1/directory11'
*resp* '150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for MLSD'
*resp* '226 Transfer complete'
*cmd* 'TYPE A'
*resp* '200 Type set to A'
*cmd* 'PASV'
*resp* '227 Entering Passive Mode (81,252,220,78,234,131).'
*cmd* 'MLSD /directory1/directory11'
*resp* '150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for MLSD'
*resp* '226 Transfer complete'
*cmd* 'TYPE I'
*resp* '200 Type set to I'
*cmd* 'PASV'
*resp* '227 Entering Passive Mode (81,252,220,78,234,126).'
*cmd* 'RETR /directory1/directory11/file111.xml'
*resp* '150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for /directory1/directory11/file111.xml (879 bytes)'
*cmd* 'NOOP'
*resp* '226 Transfer complete'
*cmd* 'TYPE I'
*resp* '550 Operation not permitted'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "..../envs/back/lib/python3.9/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 11, in <module>
  File "..../back/tools/ftpdownload.py", line 86, in get_all_files_of_directory
    self.get_all_files_of_directory(ftp_directory_root, ftp_directory_path + '/' + directory,
  File "..../back/tools/ftpdownload.py", line 86, in get_all_files_of_directory
    self.get_all_files_of_directory(ftp_directory_root, ftp_directory_path + '/' + directory,
  File "..../back/tools/ftpdownload.py", line 79, in get_all_files_of_directory
    self.download_file(current_position + '/' + file, current_output_directory + '/' + file)
  File "..../back/tools/ftpdownload.py", line 30, in download_file
    self.ftp.voidcmd('TYPE I')
  File ".../envs/back/lib/python3.9/ftplib.py", line 286, in voidcmd
    return self.voidresp()
  File "..../envs/back/lib/python3.9/ftplib.py", line 259, in voidresp
    resp = self.getresp()
  File "..../envs/back/lib/python3.9/ftplib.py", line 254, in getresp
    raise error_perm(resp)
ftplib.error_perm: 550 Operation not permitted
```

So, I tried to run the script using login after downloading each file (uncomment lines for ftpdownloader.py script)! It's work but It's too slow comparing FileZilla or other FTP client!

Can you help please ?

Comment: Isn't it the `NOOP` that breaks it? Try to remove the `self.ftp.voidcmd('NOOP')` + What FTP server is it?

Comment: Thanks @MartinPrikryl for your comment. I'm inspired by this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19692739/python-ftplib-hangs-at-end-of-transfer) to add this NOOP command because I had a freeze issue without this line. For the FTP server all I know is that it needs a secure connection. I remain available for more details. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two problems imo:

- You are not reading a response to `RETR`.
- You are not reading the responses in the order of the requests, so you misinterpret the responses. Consequently, you have many wrong assumptions which make it hard to understand the root cause.

I believe this is what is happening:

1. You send `RETR` and start the transfer.
2. You send `NOOP` and wait for a response.
3. But the server (correctly) responds to the requests in the order they are received. So it cannot respond `NOOP`, until `RETR` completes.
4. When the transfer finishes, the servers responds with `226` to the `RETR`.
5. Your code misinterprets the `226` as a response to `NOOP`
6. The server probably sends `550` as a response to `NOOP`
7. Your code does not read response to `RETR` (If it did, you will notice the mismatch between responses and answers at the first file already)
8. You send `TYPE` command for the second file
9. You read queued response `550` to `RETR` and misinterpret it as a response to `TYPE`.

I do not think the [answer you have based your code on](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19692739/850848#19693709) is correct. It indeed cannot handle more than one file, as it breaks pairing of requests and responses. If you believe the `NOOP` solves the freeze, then the correct solution might be to just send the `NOOP` command, without waiting for a response, using `FTP.putcmd`:

```
ftp.putcmd('NOOP')
noops_sent += 1
```

And then at the end of the the transfer, you have to wait for the `RETR` response using `FTP.voidresp` (see the [code of `FTP.retrbinary`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.2/Lib/ftplib.py#L421-L445)) and then wait for responses of all queued `NOOP` commands:

```
ftp.voidresp()
for _ in range(noops_sent):
    ftp.voidresp()
```

If the server is responding with `550` to `NOOP`, you will have to use `FTP.getresp`, as `FTP.voidresp` would throw on `550`.

Comment: Thanks again @Martin for your help. I have tried several solutions, but the one that works well is a solution where I remove the `NOOP` command and use the `ftp.getresp()`. Also, when the `RETR` takes more than 15 seconds, I close the FTP connection and restart a new one. Another thing, I created a list of files with an error, and at the end of the process I run script only for those. Thanks.